# Trying to display a logo in a header

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with putting a logo in my header.

Looking at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp it should be as easy as using the float property. However my logo sits below my header and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<h1>Azure Travel Agency<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" 
    style="float:right;width:150px;height:150px;"></h1>
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using. It's very hard to understand your problem otherwise.

Comment: `<h1><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" 
style="float:right;width:150px;height:150px;">Azure Travel Agency</h1>` The floating elements **must come before** the text that is meant to float around them.

Answer (score 0):

The floating elements **must come before** the text/elements that is meant to float around them:

```
<h1>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="float:right; width:150px; height:150px;" />
    Azure Travel Agency
</h1>
```

or

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="float:right; width:150px; height:150px;" />
<h1>
    Azure Travel Agency
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this method to display logo in header

```
.logo{
width: 250px;
height: 80px;
text-align: center;
background: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong with your styling! your image is inside a h1 tag! and h1 tag has block display!
use this:

```
<div style="float: right;">
<h1>
<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:150px; height:150px;" />
    Azure Travel Agency
</h1>
</div>
```

if code above doesn't work then please write all of your header code! I'll fix it.